# Preserve code coverage statistics if not calculated in SonarQube

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube5.1, jacoco-maven-plugin

In the build process of my application I use SonarQube to show some statistics regarding code quality. In particular we use it to show the code coverage of some tests that are executed nightly.

To calculate and retrieve code coverage data I use the JaCoCo Maven plugin and agent this way:

```
mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8:dump \ 
    sonar:sonar
    -Djacoco.address=TEST_SERVER \
    -Djacoco.destFile=/proj/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec \
    -Dsonar.projectKey=TEST \ 
    -Dsonar.projectName=TEST \ 
    -Dsonar.branch=TEST \
    -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=/proj/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
```

The code coverage calculated in this way is correct (as it reflects the expected coverage of some tests which are executed nightly).

But there are cases where I cannot execute the `jacoco:dump` goal to retrieve the code coverage statistics. In those cases, executing `sonar:sonar` will bring the existing code coverage statistics (calculated with previous executions of the `jacoco:dump` goal) to 0 because Sonar assumes that if no statistic is sent that statistic does not exist.

What I would like to do is that if I do not `dump` and calculate the code coverage index with JaCoCo the code coverage measures in SonarQube are not lost but are equal to the last calculated one.

Is there any way to instruct maybe the SonarQube server or the Maven Sonar plugin to preserve past code coverage statistics?

Comment: Why do you have a cobertura AND a jacoco goal in your execution ? which coverage engine do you want to use ?

Comment: Hi @benzonico, I use Cobertura for coverage of unit tests and JaCoCO for coverage coming from performance tests run on a external server (that's why I do `jacoco:dump` and not only a local instrumentation)

Comment: @bezonico, I deleted Cobertura. Now I only use JaCoCo. Do you have hint for me?